# Google Calendar Event ID global or not?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

is Event Id unique globally on the whole Google or just in my calendar?

It looks just like this: 2tdcb4eepthqj01qltpi4txfcs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ID:  Opaque identifier of the event. When creating new single or recurring events, you can specify their IDs. Provided IDs must follow these rules:
characters allowed in the ID are those used in base32hex encoding, i.e. lowercase letters a-v and digits 0-9, see section 3.1.2 in RFC2938
the length of the ID must be between 5 and 1024 characters
the ID must be unique per calendar

Due to the globally distributed nature of the system, we cannot guarantee that ID collisions will be detected at event creation time. To minimize the risk of collisions we recommend using an established UUID algorithm such as one described in RFC4122.
If you do not specify an ID, it will be automatically generated by the server.

Note that the icalUID and the id are not identical and only one of them should be supplied at event creation time. One difference in their semantics is that in recurring events, all occurrences of one event have different ids while they all share the same icalUIDs.

about the event:

Visibility of the event. Optional. Possible values are:
"default" - Uses the default visibility for events on the calendar. This is the default value.
"public" - The event is public and event details are visible to all readers of the calendar.
"private" - The event is private and only event attendees may view event details.
"confidential" - The event is private. This value is provided for compatibility reasons.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events

Comment: Is the automatically generated ID is in fact a UUID?

Comment: I doubt that. Tried UUIDv4-compliant value of "6356a7a2-f879-4cf6-8363-662b6370e07b" and google calendar says "Invalid resource id value".
In general, I think it is a good idea not to rely on google's own id generator. The rules are too obscure...